# JS to Text templating engine (asp.net-like)

Tags: javascript, code-generation

Is there anything like Microsft's T4 or ASP.NET-like templating engine to write templates in JS to generate text (or other code)?

For example (where '<=' means start of text block):

```
<#
...here goes template building code...
for(var i = 0; i < types.length; i++) {
#>
    function <#= types[i].name #> () {

    }
<#
    for(var j = 0; j < types[i].methods.length; j++) {
#>
    <#= types[i].name #>.prototype.<#= types[i].methods[j].name #> = function () {};
<#      
    }
}
#>
```

**Clarification:**

What I want is to write javascript mixed with multiline text snippets, a syntactically sweeter kind of beast than moustashe.js and likes.

Answer (score 0):

Those are called [pure javascript engines](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript_templates#Pure_JavaScript_embedded_within_HTML.2FXML_design_logic_%28ASP.2FJSP.2FPHP_or_curly_braces_style%29). They don't seem to be popular these days.